# Нахождение расстояния между двумя отрезками в пространстве

Tags: c++, геометрия

Необходимо найти кратчайшее расстояние между двумя отрезками AB и CD (координаты концов отрезков заданы в виде X,Y,Z) которые заданы в пространстве.

Я реализовал эту задачу программно перебором всех точек и нахождение самого минимального расстояния. Как это можно формульно реализовать, чтобы подставив координаты получить нужное решение?
Ниже моя реализация

```
double DIST(double Ax, double Ay, double Az, double Bx, double By, double Bz, double Cx, double Cy, double Cz, double Dx, double Dy, double Dz){
double min = 100000;
for (double t=0; t<=1; t+=0.0005)
    for (double s = 0; s <= 1; s += 0.0005)
    {
        double EF = sqrt(pow(t * Ax + (1 - t) * Bx - s * Cx - (1 - s) * Dx, 2) + pow(t * Ay + (1 - t) * By - s * Cy - (1 - s) * Dy, 2) + pow(t * Az + (1 - t) * Bz - s * Cz - (1 - s) * Dz, 2));
        if (min > EF)
            min = EF;
    }
return min;}
```

Comment: "перебором всех точек" - точно всех?

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что проще всего -

1. составляем параметрическое уравнение для первого отрезка типа x(t) = x0 + t(x1-x0), y(t) = y0 + t(y1-y0) ... и такие же для второго x(u), y(u) ... t меняется от 0 до 1, u тоже.
2. Записываем квадрат расстояния между точками как функцию d(u,t) = (x(t)-x(u))<sup>2</sup> + ...
3. Ищем ее экстремум дифференцированием. Если он в пределах [0,1] и для t, и для u - ура, найдено. Если нет - надо смотреть предельные расстояния для концов отрезков.

Словом, типичная задача поиска минимума функции двух переменных.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что мне надо найти экстремум функции double EF = sqrt(pow(t * Ax + (1 - t) * Bx - s * Cx - (1 - s) * Dx, 2) + pow(t * Ay + (1 - t) * By - s * Cy - (1 - s) * Dy, 2) + pow(t * Az + (1 - t) * Bz - s * Cz - (1 - s) * Dz, 2));

Comment: Да, но учтите, что экстремум не всегда там, где производная равна 0. Об этом иногда забывают. Надо смотреть, где эта производная нулевая, и если она за пределами рассматриваемого квадрата - то надо исследовать значения на сторонах.

Comment: фигня получается, находил экстремум в общем виде получалось, что либо s=s либо t=t

Comment: Неправильно ищете...

Answer (score 1):

Реализация на Delphi нахождения расстояния между скрещивающимися прямыми в пространстве ([wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5)) ([С версия](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/lineline.c)).

В Вашем случае (отрезки) нужно посмотреть, куда попадают концы общего перпендикуляра. Если параметры s и t выходят за пределы диапазона 0..1, то кратчайшее расстояние будет отсчитываться от соответствующего конца (концов) отрезка.

```
function LineLineDistance(const L0, L1: TLine3D; var s, t: Double): Double;
var
  u: TPoint3D;
  a, b, c, d, e, det, invdet:Double;
begin
  u := VecDiff(L1.Base, L0.Base);
  a := Dot(L0.Direction, L0.Direction);
  b := Dot(L0.Direction, L1.Direction);
  c := Dot(L1.Direction, L1.Direction);
  d := Dot(L0.Direction, u);
  e := Dot(L1.Direction, u);
  det := a * c - b * b;
  if det < eps then   
    Result := -1
  else begin
    invdet := 1 / det;
    s := invdet * (b * e - c * d);
    t := invdet * (a * e - b * d);

    Result := Distance(PointAtParam(L0, s), PointAtParam(L1, t));
  end;
end;
```